# Int 13h extended readDisk routine not functioning

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, disk, osdev

I've been trying to read a few sectors in my bootloader code (MBR), using the extended read function `AH = 42H` and `INT 13H`
But no error is shown, and the sectors are not read.
So far, while debugging with Bochs and Qemu, what I've noticed is:
(I set the dl register accordingly)

The carry flag is not set, so there is no error
Nothing is read into the second sector, that is 0x7e00 is filled with 0's
Which also means that any code after `jmp sect2` is not being executed.
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the code for the readDisk routine:

```
readDisk:

    pusha
    push ds
    push si

    mov word [DAP_START_SECTOR] , cx
    mov word [DAP_NUM_SECTORS] , ax
    mov word [DAP_OFFSET], di
    mov word [DAP_SEGMENT], es
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, DAP

    mov dl, 0x80
    ;0x80 for hard drive
    ;0x00 for first floppy
    mov ax, 0x42
    int 13h
    jc fail

    pop si
    pop ds
    popa
    ret
align 4
DAP:
    DAP_SIZE:           db 0x10
    DAP_UNUSED:         db 0x00
    DAP_NUM_SECTORS:    dw 0x00
    DAP_PTR_TO_SECTOR: 
        DAP_OFFSET:     dw 0x00
        DAP_SEGMENT:    dw 0x00

    DAP_START_SECTOR:   dq 0x00

fail:
 mov si,DISKFAILMSG
 call printf
 mov dx,ax
 call printh
 jmp $
DISKFAILMSG db "disk read ERROR",0
```

Here's the code for the bootloader:

```
[org 0x7c00]  ;start at 0x7c00
[bits 16]

section .data ; constants, put under the magic number, at the end
section .bss  ; variables, similarly at the end
section .text ; code

global main   ;main is global and is our entry point

main:
            ;clear the seg registers, to prevent any offset buffer

cli         ;clear interrupts

jmp 0x0000:ZeroSeg

ZeroSeg:
    xor ax,ax   ; clear ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov fs,ax
    mov gs,ax

    ;cleared the seg

    mov sp, 0x7c00      ;0x7c00 = main?
    cld         ; clear the direction flag, which controlls the order of reading
                ; string
    sti         ; set interrupt
    push ax
    xor ax,ax
    ;mov dl, 10000000b
    int 13h
    jc fail
    pop ax






;mov al,2       ; read 2 sectors
;mov cl,2       ; sectors start from 1, sector 1 is bootloader, so read sector 2

mov ax,0x07e0
mov es,ax
xor di,di

mov ax, 0x0002      ; number of sectors read
mov cx, 0x0001  ;absolute number (not addr of start sector (sector 0 is bootloader here))


call readDisk


call loadE820
mov dx,ax       ;trial 1: received 6 entries
call printh

;TODO Configure Proper video modes
;call videoMode









jmp sect2       ; works if sect2 is read

%include "./printf.asm"
%include "./readDisk.asm"
%include "./printh.asm"
%include "./loadE820.asm"
;%include "./videoMode.asm"

%include "./gdt.asm"
;
;
;
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ;padding
dw 0xaa55               ;Magic number


;sector 2  

sect2:
    call EnableA20

    mov si, MESSAGE
    call printf

    call checklm

    mov si,DISKSUCCESSMSG
    call printf

    ;call keyb



;call videoMode
call enterProtected
;
;
;;*******************************TEST CODE********************************
;
;
;;call testvid32
;
mov si,DISKSUCCESSMSG
call printf


jmp $

%include "./TestA20.asm"
%include "./EnableA20.asm"

%include "./checklm.asm"
;
;
;
;
;
MESSAGE db "Hello, World!",0x0a,0x0d,0
DISKSUCCESSMSG db "Welcome to my first OS!",0ah,0dh,0



times 512-($-sect2) db 0

sect3:
%include "./enterProtected.asm"
keyb:
        mov ah,00h
        int 16h
        cmp ah,0
        je keyb
        ret
%include "./testvid32.asm"
```

Comment: `mov` to `ss` should be immediately followed by `mov` to `sp`.

Comment: @ecm : that would be true if he hadn't issued CLI as his first instruction. With CLI the order that he sets things won't matter given that with interrupts off with just the bootstrap processor going wouldn't allow for anything to occur between the update of SS and SP. I had noticed that as well. To avoid an atomicity bug doesn't require that SS be followed by an SP update, just that somehow the bootloader makes it atomic. Using CLI also would work if he was running on a defective 8088 where interrupts may not be off for the instruction following an SS update.

Comment: @Michael Petch: Running the loader in a debugger running on the same machine (not external to it) will cause SS to be set first without SP being set. So even with interrupts disabled the SP change should be done in the subsequent instruction.

Comment: If we want to be nitpicky, if we were running on an 8088 with a defective CPU CLI would have to be used since not all 8088's disabled interrupts for the instruction following the SS update.

Comment: @Michael Petch: As far as I'm concerned, we should do **both** `cli` and immediately setting SP after setting SS.

Comment: Writing code to keep a hosted debugger happy isn't really relevant. A lot of software use to refuse to work with hosted debuggers in the old days and it wasn't because of bugs in the software. The problem isn't that the hosted debugger could get screwed up, it is the debugger is running with no way to be protected because of CPU limitations . That's a problem between the processor and the debugger, not the running software. To get beyond that we had ICE debuggers. Then we got virtualization, MMUs etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this could be an issue of the boot image and how you create it or something related to the code you don't show, I suspect the real problem is likely this error:

```
mov ax, 0x42
int 13h
```

The BIOS call number 0x42 should be in *AH*, not *AX*. It should read:

```
mov ah, 0x42
int 13h
```

---

Although not your problem, it is generally not a good idea to hard code the boot drive number when calling disk functions. Rather than force *DL* to 0x80 you can simply use the value in *DL* that was passed to the bootloader by the BIOS. Your disk reset [Int 13h/AH=0h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0605.htm) call does this correctly, but your [Int 13/AH=42h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0708.htm) extended disk read doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for that, it resolved my problem.
And yes, noted, I'm now storing the drive number for later use.